# configure LDT with torch but 'path' is a nil value

Tags: torch

I configure my LDT with torch using [this tutorial](http://www.lighting-torch.com/2015/07/27/configuring-eclipse-with-torch/).
But when i tried to excute a torch program, it returns such a error:

```
    lua: ./util/BatchLoaderUnk.lua:14: attempt to index global 'path' (a nil value)
```

But i know 'path' is a in-build metatable.

Comment: path = require 'pl.path'  works. but what i wonder is why this should added this line of code. Isn't the path loaded to the environment automaticly?

Comment: What happens if you execute this in terminal? `th -e "print(path.join('a','b'))"`